# can I write value(Python file will update this value continuously) to json file continuously?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to write python output to json file. I am able to achieve it but it only happens when I stop executing program.

This is my python program file

```
def WriteJson(data):
   j = json.dumps(data)
   with open('Example.json','w') as f:
      f.write(j)
      f.close()

i = 1
data = {}
while(1):
  time.sleep(0.5 )
  if i <= 35:
     i+=5
     data = {"i": i}
     WriteJson(data)
     print(data)
     time.sleep(2)
  else:
     i = 25
     data = {"i": i}
     j = json.dumps(data)
     WriteJson(data)
     print(data)
     time.sleep(2)
```

When I execute this program I see Example.json

```
{"i": 30}
```

I want something like this in Example.json

```
{"i": 6}
{"i": 11}
{"i": 16}
{"i": 21}
{"i": 26}
{"i": 31}
{"i": 36}
{"i": 25}
{"i": 30}
```

If anyone here can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), opening a file in `"w"` (write) mode will truncate the file before writing to it, but opening a file in `"a"` (append) mode allows you to write to the end of the file without removing its contents. So, you could do something like this:

```py
def WriteJson(data):
   j = json.dumps(data)
   with open('Example.json','a') as f:
      f.write(j)
      f.write('\n')

i = 1
data = {}
while(1):
  time.sleep(0.5 )
  if i <= 35:
     i+=5
     data = {"i": i}
     WriteJson(data)
     print(data)
     time.sleep(2)
  else:
     i = 25
     data = {"i": i}
     j = json.dumps(data)
     WriteJson(data)
     print(data)
     time.sleep(2)
```

That should append to the file, rather than overwriting it.

An alternative which should be more performant, but changes your code slightly more, is to open the file once, rather than every time you need to write to it. We use `buffering=1` to ensure writes are immediately written to the file, rather than being written once the program finishes, since your question specifies want writes to be completed immediately:

```py
def WriteJson(data, file):
    j = json.dumps(data)
    f.write(j)
    f.write('\n')

with open('Example.json', 'w', buffering=1) as f:
    i = 1
    # ...
    WriteJson(data, f)
```